# Uploaded 8-bit PNGs losing alpha transparency (using ImageMagick)

Tags: upload

I found searching through other questions here that:

> Currently the images are being cleansed on upload, which means that
>   they are being re-saved to make sure that no malicious code is
>   injected in them.

The problem I have is that **optimized 8-bit PNGs with alpha transparency** (like the ones TinyPng creates) are **transformed on upload to indexed, non-alpha transparency PNGs** - and as a result they look very bad.

I'm not even using any transforms, so this is just from the "cleansing" that Craft does automatically on upload.

I initially was using the GD library but then I installed ImageMagick and even forced Craft to use ImageMagick through the config setting - nothing helped

Image uploads work just fine with ImageMagick, except the PNG issue described above.

Is there something I need to configure in the ImageMagick library or it's PHP plugin? Or can I disable the "cleansing" that Craft does? (I don't want to do that since I love the added security, but I really need to use transparent, compressed PNGs in my website designs).

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's a PNG image, before and after upload (just posted the links, since theimage is big and I didn't want to mess up the thread):

[Before the upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJvpY.png) - shows as RGB mode in Photoshop - has alpha transparency. Was saved as PNG 24 from PS then compressed with TinyPNG

[After the upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0I9b.png) - shows as Indexed mode in Photoshop - no alpha transparency - was re-saved by Craft on upload from the CP.

Comment: What version of Craft? Can you post up both images, the one before/after Craft?

Comment: This could end up being a bug in Craft.  Can you send a PNG over to support@buildwithcraft.com and reference this post so we can look into it?

Comment: @RitterKnight - using latest version of Craft as of this post (2.4.2699) Edited the post to add link to sample before and after images.

Comment: @BradBell - I did what you said, also attached the error logs, db backup and template files. Thanks!

Comment: Also interesting to note that Craft's version has the sRGB color profile embedded making the file larger as well.